# MSSQL collation for Greek Language to use with PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, unicode, sql-server-2012

I am using MSSQL database and our MSSQL server is 2012. The database connection is based on ODBC.

The collation for the database is - "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS".  The datatypes for columns is also nvarchar.

I am using php for my web application. I am trying to fetch the data from database and it returns properly for english language.

But for Greek it is not working and it displays string like "????". We tried several ways but it won't worked. Is there any solution so that we get the proper data if it is in any language ?

Is there any way so that we can handle this thing while making database connection ? Please help me.

```
$uid='username';
$pwd='password';
$dsnless = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=tcp:.\sqlexpress;Database=dbname;Uid=dbusername;Pwd=dbpassword"
// ODBC Connecion
$conn = odbc_connect($dsnless, $uid, $pwd) or die('Error connecting to     database server. Server says: '.htmlspecialchars(odbc_errormsg()));
// Making Query
$sql = "SELECT columnName FROM TableName";
$rs=odbc_exec($conn, $sql);if (!$rs){
  echo "Error";
} else {
  while (odbc_fetch_row($rs)){
$col1=odbc_result($rs, "columnName");
echo $col1;  // This columns returns "?????" for Greek Characters
}
}exit;
```

Comment: Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32696216/how-to-insert-greek-characters-into-sqlserver-table

Comment: Please show your code and give us sample data in order to see where the problem is. In general, the answer to your question is "yes"

Comment: hey  Nenad Zivkovic, Please see the code in question